# How to sync from Bintray to Maven Central without knowing Maven

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, maven-release-plugin, bintray

I recently started working as a developer and I need to sync a repo from [bintray](https://bintray.com/johnreed2/maven/scala-trace-debug) to [maven central](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-21413). I have never used Maven or the mvn command line utility ever - I started as a Scala sbt developer.

I was told to follow [these instructions](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_syncingartifactswithmavencentral.html) but I cannot because I don't know Maven or Gradle or Nexus or any of these other things - all I know is [sbt bintray](https://github.com/softprops/bintray-sbt).

> "In the Maven Central tab, all you have to do is enter your Maven Central User token key and User token password"

I have never heard of Maven Central keys or user token passwords, but without any prior knowlege I could use some instructions.

Comment: You need to request one at the Sonatype issue tracker

Answer (score 0):

You need to create [an account](https://issues.sonatype.org/secure/Signup!default.jspa) in Sonatype JIRA. Those will be your https://oss.sonatype.org (and Maven Central) username and *password*. Then you need to create a [new issue](https://issues.sonatype.org/secure/CreateIssue.jspa?issuetype=21&pid=10134) to set your permissions right. Once done, you'll be able to login with the credentials to https://oss.sonatype.org and get the user token needed for Bintray from the user account management there.